# IBM Watson Clinical Annotator API Python SDK - adding optional parameter throws a 400

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson

I am following the API documents for analyzing text via the API docs [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/wh-acd?code=python#runpipeline) and the examples on github [here](https://github.com/IBM/whcs-python-sdk/blob/master/examples/notebooks/annotator_for_clinical_data.ipynb).  When I add the optional parameter to the annotator to get all of the codes like this:

```
   anno_cd = acd.Annotator(
      name='concept_detection',
      parameters = {'include_optional_fields':'medical_codes'})
```

I get this:

> Error Occurred:  Code  400  Message  Bad Request  CorrelationId
> 820af2f3-0b25-477a-bde5-20fc57fd4a4d

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are those valid parameters?

Comment: Was not - see the answer below.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the way the parameters were set.  You need to build a collection inside a collection.  This works:

anno_cd = acd.Annotator(
name='concept_detection',
parameters = {"expanded": ["true"],"include_optional_fields":["medical_codes"]})